# how do i get sound from speakers and headset for different apps?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, headset

How can I make it so some apps have sound coming out of my pc speakers, and others through the headset? when i have headset in it shows no apps in speaker options

Comment: This would have to be a specific capability of the audio system hardware/driver, or you'd have to use a rather complicated piece of software such as Virtual Audio Cable and hope your audio system is compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible, depending on the model of PC. In most headphone jacks there is a physical switch that disconnects the internal speaker.